# IIS Url Rewrite Add Index.php to

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have problem with IIS and url rewrite...

I'm getting urls like this
http://www.mywebsite.com/this-is-my-article

I need to rewrite it to
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/this-is-my-article

I was trying patterns and conditions that in theory should work, but they don't. After few hours of searching and trying I decided to ask you for help.

Could anyone tell me, how to set URL Rewrite module?

best regards
M

Comment: Learn how to debug with FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then you can help yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule, if you have any questions, please let me know.

```
<rule name="test1">
   <match url=".*$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hello Samwu... thanks for the answer... The point is that there is no one article only... there is more or them so I need some kind of universal rule that will handle all of them. When I use the console to enter the rule, I need to put there: pattern, match and action. 
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You mean this-is-my-article is not fixed? If so, then you can change the parameter to `^.*$`   `(<match url="^.*$" />)`, it can match any data. If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement give some examples.

Comment: You're right! That works for me. Thank you!

Comment: Can you [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?  This can help more people solve the same problem.